# Remove duplicates form a list in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list like this :

```
['35UP\nPLx', '35UP']
```

I need a list of unique elements:

```
['PLx', '35UP']
```

i have tried this :

```
veh_line = list(dict.fromkeys(filter['p_Mounting_Location'].replace('\n',',', regex=True).tolist()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.splitlines` with `set`.

**Ex:**

```
data = ['35UP\nPLx', '35UP']
result = list(set(j for i in data for j in i.splitlines()))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['35UP', 'PLx']
```